# Toolkit MapExtension doesn't exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm following this popular guide 
http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-2/
to add pushpins on a Map control in my app.

The problem is: when I try to use the toolkit, for example:

```
<toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
```

or

```
<toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

the compiler returns that the element was not found and to verify if there's the assembly reference for that.

Now, I have enabled the Maps functionality on the AppManifest and in the XAML of the map's page I've added this:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

So I really don't know why this happens.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead:
`xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

Use this:

`xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`